# R - Looping within a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have used the following code to calculate the log-likelihood of a function where the x parameters (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) are uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1, but the function is also dependent on the values of t (which is a vector).

```
library(expm)
t <- seq(10,1000,by=5)

x1 <- runif(1,0,1)
x2 <- runif(1,0,1)
x3 <- runif(1,0,1)
x4 <- runif(1,0,1)
x5 <- runif(1,0,1)

p <- matrix(c(1,0,0), nrow=1, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

q <- matrix(c(x1,x2,x3), nrow=3, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)

likely <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(t)) {
likely[i] <- p%*%expm(matrix(c(-(x4+x1)*t[i],x4*t[i],0,0,-(x5+x2)*t[i],x5*t[i],0,0,-x3*t[i]), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))%*%q
}

log.likely <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(t)) {
log.likely[i] <- log(likely[i])
}

L3 <- -(sum(log.likely))
L3
```

My question is: how do I run this code say, 100 times, for different values of the x parameters? I already have a loop within the code to run through the different values of t. But now I need to loop over different values of x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a data frame or matrix with all the parameter combinations you want to check. `expand.grid` is good for this, e.g, `params = expand.grid(x1 = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.72), x2 = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2), ...)`. Then make a loop that goes over `1:nrow(params)`, running the code you aleady have for each line, and storing the result.

Comment: It might be easiest if you convert your existing code into a function that takes `x1`-`x5` as arguments.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the response! I now have something like this: `params <- expand.grid(x1 = runif(10,0,1), x2 = runif(10,0,1), x3 = runif(10,0,1), x4 = runif(10,0,1), x5 = runif(10,0,1))`
But I'm not sure how to store matrices in a loop. For example, this doesn't work: `for (k in 1:nrow(params)) {
q[k] <- matrix(c(x1,x2,x3), nrow=3, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
}`

Comment: Is `q`a list of length = `nrow(params)`? That might work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're going for or not, but this will allow you to run your code however many times you want to, and store the results in a list containing all of the x values and the log likelyhood for the values.

```
log.likelyhood <- function(){
  require(expm)

  t <- seq(10,1000,by=5)

  x1 <- runif(1,0,1)
  x2 <- runif(1,0,1)
  x3 <- runif(1,0,1)
  x4 <- runif(1,0,1)
  x5 <- runif(1,0,1)

  p <- matrix(c(1,0,0), nrow=1, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

  q <- matrix(c(x1,x2,x3), nrow=3, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)

  likely <- vector()

  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    likely[i] <- p%*%expm(matrix(c(-(x4+x1)*t[i],x4*t[i],0,0,-(x5+x2)*t[i],x5*t[i],0,0,-x3*t[i]), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))%*%q
  }

  log.likely <- vector()

  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    log.likely[i] <- log(likely[i])
  }

  L3 <- -(sum(log.likely))

  return(list(xvals = c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), L3 = L3))
}

results <- replicate(100, log.likelyhood(), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! It ran perfectly for the time vector that I provided. However, my real time vector has a large number of elements so I'm still waiting for the results to be generated. I'm not sure exactly how long that'll take, but thanks again for the answer!